# Azure Release Pipeline does not have enough permissions to deploy Bicep/ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

When I try to deploy my Bicep template through a DevOps release pipeline I get the following error:

> Deployment failed with multiple errors: 'Authorization failed for
> template resource '1525ed81-ad25-486e-99a3-124abd455499' of type
> 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions'. The client
> '378da07a-d663-4d11-93d0-9c383eadcf45' with object id
> '378da07a-d663-4d11-93d0-9c383eadcf45' does not have permission to
> perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write' at
> scope
> '/subscriptions/8449f684-37c6-482b-8b1a-576b999c77ef/resourceGroups/rgabpddt/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/1525ed81-ad25-486e-99a3-124abd455499'.:Authorization
> failed for template resource '31c1daec-7d4a-4255-8528-169fc45fc14d' of
> type 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments'.

I understand through [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/permission-authorising-release-pipeline-against-su/370952) that I have to grant "something" the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator` role.

But I don't understand what user has the ObjectId `378da07a-d663-4d11-93d0-9c383eadcf45`.

I tried to look it up with the following `az` CLI command, but it says that it cannot find a resource with that Id:

```
az ad user show --id 378da07a-d663-4d11-93d0-9c383eadcf45
```

The response it returns:

```
Resource '378da07a-d663-4d11-93d0-9c383eadcf45' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

I'm a but clueless here. What do I exactly have to grant permission?

Comment: if you deploying from azure devops, there is probably a service connection associated. you re probably using a service principal. so `az ad sp` shoudl help here

Comment: @Thomas It's not a service principal. I used that command to list all principals, but the ObjectId is not in there.

Comment: have you tried checking the appId ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use service connection in DevOps pipeline, for example Azure Resource Manager service connection, it will create a service principal(app registry) on `Azure portal-> Active Directory`. You can find the service principal by clicking the link on service connection:

[image]

When you deploy with service connection, please make sure you have give correct permission for this service principal on target resource, like mentioned `Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write`. Suggest to give contributor role on the resource. Otherwise it will reports the error in your pipeline log.

When you add the role, you will find the `object id`, it's `different` with service principal `application ID` or `object id`.

It's [azure role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles) not Azure AD role. You can find the difference in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#differences-between-azure-roles-and-azure-ad-roles).

[image]

Comment: I clicked the link of the service connection, but non of the Id's matched the ObjectId given in the release pipeline. But I tried to use the `Display name` of the service connection. Which is also presented when you click on `Manage Service Principal`. I was able to find the service principal using the display name. So I assigned the correct roles to it and now it all works.